# Convert /etc/network/interfaces to netplan

Tags: server, netplan, samba4

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rf7Hk8qWt1Q) tutorial for making an Ubuntu active directory domain controller with Samba.

The problem I have run into, is that he is using Ubuntu Server 13.10, and I am using the latest, 18.04.  Somewhere between these 2 versions, Ubuntu stopped using `/etc/network/interfaces` and started using `netplan`.

Therefore, when he says to modify `/etc/network/interfaces`, and add:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.2.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.2.0
broadcast 192.168.2.255
gateway 192.168.2.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.100 8.8.8.8
dns-search <domain name>.local
```

I get an error message that says:

> ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.

I did some research, and found that now this should be stored in `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`.  This file does not exist.  Should I create it?  Also, what is the equivalent of what he said to put in the file, for `netplan`?

Edit: The output for `ls /etc/netplan` is `50-cloud-init.yaml`, and the output for `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` is:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `ls /etc/netplan` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I edited it with the information you requested.  Thanks

Comment: Is this a cloud instance or a virtual machine or a simple (home?) server?

Comment: Currently it's a virtual machine, but if it works, I will configure an actual server the same way.

Comment: Convert to a simple (home?) server or a cloud instance?

Comment: a simple server (not cloud)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let’s follow the recommendation included in the 50-cloud-init.yaml file. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "network: {config: disabled}"  >  /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg
exit
```

Next, let’s remove the file and simultaneously back it up:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml  ~/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

Next, verify the ethernet interface name with the command:

```
ifconfig
```

Substitute the interface you found below if not enp0s3.

Now let’s write a new file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Write the following:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.2.100/24
      gateway4: 192.168.2.1
      nameservers:
          search: [<domain name>.local]
          addresses: [192.168.1.100, 8.8.8.8]
```

Spacing, indentation, etc. are crucial and must be exact. Proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Now do:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Reboot.

Comment: It worked for me when I changed the "1" in `addresses: [192.168.1.100, 8.8.8.8]` to a "2", to match `192.168.2.100/24`.  Is that a typo or is it supposed to be different?

Comment: I simply transferred your numbers from your original question. I assumed, guessed, really, that you used hypothetical numbers in your question. In fact, I suspect that the DNS nameserver should be 192.168.2.1 8.8.8.8. Glad it's working!