# How do I use cloud-init to apply netplan?

Tags: netplan, cloud-init

After I manually edit `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/50-curtin-networking.cfg`, how do I tell `cloud-init` to update `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`? In other words, it doesn't make sense to manually update both files; what's the standard process to re-apply the netplan?

Answer (score 4):

As Lismatro said, once you create your netplan config, generate then apply it.

In your cloud-init config, first tells netplan to use custom config:

```
write_files:
- path: /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-custom-networking.cfg
  permissions: '0644'
  content: |
    network: {config: disabled}
```

Then create the netplan config (still in cloud-init config). Here is a simple example. Find more ways to configure network interfaces with netplan [here](https://netplan.io/examples/):

```
- path: /etc/netplan/my-new-config.yaml
  permissions: '0644'
  content: |
    network:
        version: 2
        ethernets:
            ens3:
                dhcp4: true
```

Finally tell cloud-init to use it (again, still in cloud-init config):

```
runcmd:
 - rm /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
 - netplan generate
 - netplan apply
```

Comment: thank you, good sir, I was looking for this to find out why my cloud-init configuration was not applying

Answer (score 2):

The cloud-init confuguration files are not the place the change your network configuration after first boot, because the network configuration will only be generated once by cloud-init (on first boot).

You can however change the netplan config file directly. Then use the following commands as root to enable your changes. They will stick across boots.

```
netplan generate
netplan apply
```

Only the command 'cloud-init clean' will regenerate the 50...yaml file, but I dont think you want that. That would reset everything, including hostname en machine-id (resulting in a new max-address and a new dhcp ip address).

Comment: My netplan file says this at the top: "
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
"
It's still ok to edit this file?

Comment: For an explanation on the "not across an instance" warning, refer to my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117469/what-does-changes-to-it-will-not-persist-across-an-instance-actually-mean-in-5/1149749#1149749